# Can I disable template caching for local development?

Tags: templating, cache, multi-environment

Can I disable template caching for local development?
For example: setting a environmentVariable in a config file?
Or is this possible in the future?

Comment: Yes. See my [answer](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/106/125) to this other question about caching.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When working with multiple environments you most likely want to disable caching for all but one environment, because Craft saves the absolute URL to entries/assets in the cache.

I achieved this by setting a custom variable in general.php

```
'craft.dev' => array(
    'cache' => true,
    'environmentVariables' => array(...),
)

 '192.168.178.20' => array(
    'cache' => false,
    'environmentVariables' => array(...),
)
```

and then add a conditional to the cache function in the template

```
{% cache if craft.config.cache %}
    {# ... #}
{% endcache %}
```

With this setup I can now access the cached content on craft.dev and open the site on another devices in the network on 192.168.178.20 without having problems with cached urls.

I first posted this on another question about caching: ["What are the best practices for using the {% cache %} tag?"](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/105/what-are-the-best-practices-for-using-the-cache-tag), which might also be of interest for you!

*(**Edit:** Since Craft 2.2 it is possible to use `if` condition with the `cache` tag, so you don't have to do messy constructs like `unless not` any more.)*

Comment: Nice, Christian ;)

Answer (score 33):

As of **Craft 2.4**, it is now possible to use the [`enableTemplateCaching`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#enableTemplateCaching) config value.

```
'enableTemplateCaching' => false,
```

Simply add that to your local environment in `config/general.php`, and it'll disable the `cache` tags entirely.

Answer (score 5):

I found this post and the answer by @carlcs helpful.  However, I find the phrasing `unless not` in the cache logic a bit hard to wrap my head around.  I want to note here an alternative to the syntax above that I found more intuitive:

**general.php**

```
return array(
    'live' => array(
        'cache' => true
    ),

    'local' => array(
        'cache' => false
    )
)
```

**cache tag which only runs in live environment**

```
{% cache if craft.config.cache %}
   ...
{% endcache %}
```

Comment: Using `if` with the `cache` tag wasn't possible when I wrote the answer. But you're right, it reads better and I actually use it myself that way. Thanks for the reminder to change it here, too.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer to use caching all the time. Since developing with caching disabled can be really confusing when something refuses to work in production with caching enabled. If you develop with caching enabled, you'd probably find issues while developing.

Better to clear the cache folder if you need to refresh.