# Access environment information in template

Tags: templating, multi-environment, devmode

Is there a way to check what environment craft is running on - ie, dev or not dev - via the template.

For example:

```
{%if env is 'dev'%}
    hello dev
{% else %}
   hello world
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When developing locally on Craft you would most likely have `devMode => true` set in your config file and set to false for your production config.

app/config/general.php

```
return array(
 'mydevdomain.dev' => array(
   'devMode' => true
 ),
 'mylivedomain.com' => array(
   'devMode' => false
 )
);
```

So you could test whether craft is in dev mode and respond to that:

```
{% if craft.config.devMode %}
  You are in dev mode
{% else %}
  You are not in devmode
{% endif %}
```

Comment: You can also define totally custom variables in the same way (e.g. [`'cache' => false` → `{% if craft.config.cache %}`](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/678/125))

Comment: In my opinion, this is a risky thing to do: it's not inconceivable that an inexperienced developer might be tempted to switch on dev mode in production to debug something 'guerilla' style, which could in turn trigger these conditionals unintentionally. Yes, that's a bad idea, but it could happen. Other devs might even switch on devMode in production by accident.

Comment: deprecated. now its `craft.app.config.general.devMode`

Answer (score 40):

In Craft 3 you can get the env using the `getenv()` function:

```
{% set env = getenv('ENVIRONMENT') %}

{% if env == 'dev' %}
    hello dev
{% else %}
    hello world
{% endif %}
```

Or via the app’s config service:

```
{% set env = craft.app.config.env %}
```

There's a bit more information about the .env file in the docs for [Environmental Configuration](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/environments.html).

Comment: This really helped with setting up some new custom environment variables outside of the default Craft 3 ones for a project. 

Comment: This worked wonders! Thanks. Very handy when you want to work off local files in dev, but need the absolute URL on the production site.

Comment: THank for this simple answer.

Answer (score 7):

You can set a custom "environment label" variable inside config/general.php:

```
return array(
    // ALL ENVIRONMENTS
    '*' => array(
    ),
    // LOCAL
    'mysite.local' => array(
        'env' => 'local'
    ),
    // DEV
    'dev.mysite.com' => array(
        'env' => 'dev'
    ),
    // PROD
    'www.mysite.com' => array(
        'env' => 'prod'
    )
);
```

Then use the `craft.config` variable to output the `env` variable for the current environment:

```
{% if craft.config.env == 'dev' %}
    hello dev
{% else %}
    hello world
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but just an update:

If you're on Craft CMS v3+, `craft.config.[setting-name]` has been deprecated.
Use `craft.app.config.general.[setting-name]` instead.

So if you wanted to check if you were in `dev` environment, you'd do `craft.app.config.general.devMode`, this returns a `boolean` value.