# Template caching tag storage options

Tags: templating, cache, caching

I can see that normal caching can have it's storage specified, but I would specifically like to be able to set the caching storage method for the template tag {% cache %}.

At the moment it appears to be hitting our MySQL database very hard and so I would like to consider using something like Redis instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, the template {% cache %} tag can only cache to the database.

See Brandon's comment [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/105/what-are-the-best-practices-for-using-the-cache-tag/107#107) ("Template caches always go to the database").

Comment: Shame as I don't think a MySQL database is necessarily the best storage for this sort of thing. Be good if it became a configurable option in the future.

Comment: Absolutely agree with you on that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yea I would like to see some more static in memory/file store as well (as plug or native) -> Page needs 1.7 secs for first byte..really wanna push that down to 150ms or so.

Not everyone can put varnish or fastly before the page :)