# Config variable does not exist

Tags: conditional, devmode, caching

I'm trying to set up caching and have it disabled for my local environment using `{% cache unless craft.config.devMode %}`. This works fine on non-local environments, but on my local environment I'm getting the error `Method "devMode" for object "Craft\ConfigVariable" does not exist`. Even though it does, this is my config file:

```
return array(
    '*' => array(
        'addTrailingSlashesToUrls' => true,
        'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
        'enableCsrfProtection' => true,
        'cpTrigger' => 'example-admin',
        'siteUrl' => (isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) && $_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https://" : "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
        'environmentVariables' => array(
            'basePath' => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/data/uploads/',
            'baseURL' => (isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) && $_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https://" : "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/data/uploads/',
        )
    ),
    '.local' => array(
        'devMode' => true
    )
);
```

If I `{{ dump(craft.config.devMode) }}` I get `bool(true)` so it is being set, it's just when being used in the cache conditional.

Comment: Strange. What does this do: `{% if craft.config.devMode %}Check DevMode{% endif %}`?

Comment: That worked, must be character encoding as when I manually typed out `{% cache unless craft.config.devMode %}` it worked.

Comment: No solution to this, but what about setting a new variable `'cache' => true`? Then you can set it independently from dev mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it was an issue with character encoding. I copied the `{% cache unless craft.config.devMode %}` from [What are the best practices for using the {% cache %} tag?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/105/what-are-the-best-practices-for-using-the-cache-tag).

When I manually retyped out the conditional it worked properly.