# Axios post function got 400 bad request

Tags: ajax, csrf, vue

I created a Vue component. And in this component, I use axios to send post request when it's mounted, CSRF token also included, but still got 400 status. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 3):

Just found the solution:

```
npm install qs
```

and

```
import qs from 'qs'

...
const actions = {
    auth({ commit }, { email, password }) {

        axios.post('url', qs.stringify({
            your token data here
        })).then((res) => {
            console.log(res.data)
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: This was really helpful but I had to capitalize the Q in `Qs.stringify()` since I wasn't bundling the library with my other js code. If you want a full example of this in action using Vue and Axios, go here: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/30713/4433